# Angular: Ace Editor Error 'defaultToken'

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, ace-editor

Facing some error all of sudden in ace-editor using angular and es6.

Was working before so not sure changed.

***Error:***

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultToken' of undefined
```

***Code*** (in ace.js which fails):

```
for (var key in this.states) {
    var state = this.states[key];
    var ruleRegExps = [];
    var matchTotal = 0;
    var mapping = this.matchMappings[key] = {defaultToken: "text"};
    var flag = "g";

    var splitterRurles = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
        var rule = state[i];
        if (rule.defaultToken)
```

What boggles me is that this was working before and now it's not. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: `state[i]` returns `undefined`

Comment: check `rule` exists before accessing `defaultToken` from it like `if(rule &&rule.defaultToken)`

Comment: i know the solutions to check programmatically for `state` or check if `rule` exists but I was wondering if anyone could point out why this error would occur suddenly and not always. More of a `ace.js` question than a javascript one. Thanks for the inputs though.

Comment: Try creating demo page reproducing the issue, it may be caused by something adding an enumerable property on Object.prototype